# How to invoke value of variables enclosed in single quotes and seperated by space in UNIX?

Tags: variables, unix, invoke

```
export a='123.gmail.com 345.gmail.com 123.facebook.com 345.facebook.com'

export b='123.gmail.com 345.gmail.com'

export c='123.facebook.com 345.facebook.com'
```

Now I am exporting these values to other script and while invoking the values in other script. 
I have the below code :

```
for hosts in { a }
do
```

Now my questions is: 
at this point I need to check wether the hosts value holds the value in variable `b` or variable `c`, 
i.e. I want to check wether host is holding `b` variables or `c` variables values.

Can anyone please tell me how do we get this?

Answer (score 0):

With `[[` you can use special shell features:

```
for host in $a; do
   if [[ "$b" = *${host}* ]]; then
      echo "${host} found in b ($b)";
   fi
done
```

Comment: its looping through only one value of b 
its not taking both the values of b.

Comment: It loops through the values of a. For all a-values it will look if the value is a substring of the complete string b (b with 2 values). The `*${host}*` has wildcards on both sides, so it will match b when host is the first or second field in b.

Comment: echo "Welcome to test script"                                                   
a='123.com 345.com 123.in 345.in'                                               
echo $a | wc -w                                                                 
b='123.com 345.com'                                                             
echo $b                                                                         
c='123.in 345.in'

Comment: host='123.com'                                                                  
echo "Displaying VAlue of Host $host"                                           
if [[ "$b" = *${host}* ]]; then
   echo "${host} found in b ($b)";                   
fi

Comment: when i run the above script it checks only for one value of b not both the values

Comment: if [[ "$b" = *${host}* ]]; then
   echo "${host} found in b ($b)";                   
fi
for this it does not give me any result  but if interchange b and host values in if condition it checks only for one value and gives below error:

Comment: Welcome to test script                                                          
4                                                                               
123.com 345.com                                                                 
123.in 345.in                                                                   
Displaying VAlue of Host 123.com                                                
sh: 345.com*: unknown operand

Comment: It is essebtial that you type the two asteriks. Without the stars it will try to match the complete string $b. Do not write `if [[ "$b" = ${host} ]];`, please write `if [[ "$b" = *${host}* ]];`